# PlaySound function won't work for my hand-made wav files, even though they open fine in windows media player

Tags: c++, audio, wav, playsound

I'm using [VS 2015 for desktop] and I'm coding in c++. I have used audacity to record wav files and then used PlaySound to play them, and they work fine.

I've literally opened up fstreams and put in, byte by byte, the header and data for a new wav file. (I admit, almost all of this code is copied from online, but I still dissected it to learn for myself.) The synthesized wav files, from this code, can play in any audio player (including audacity) just as the audacity recordings can, but they don't work for PlaySound. The header settings are the same, I've checked.

```
namespace little_endian_io {
    template <typename Word> std::ostream& write_word(std::ostream& outs, Word value, unsigned size = sizeof(Word))
    {
        for (; size; --size, value >>= 8)
            outs.put(static_cast <char> (value & 0xFF));
        return outs;
    }
}

using namespace little_endian_io;

ofstream out(pathpat + "\\voces\\_audiophiles\\outputs.wav", std::ios::binary);

///HEADER
out << "RIFF----WAVEfmt ";
write_word(out, 16, 4);  // no extension data
write_word(out, 1, 2);  // PCM - integer samples
write_word(out, 2, 2);  // stereo
write_word(out, 44100, 4);  // Hz
write_word(out, 176400, 4);  // (Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8
write_word(out, 4, 2);  // data block size (size of two integer samples, one for each channel, in bytes)
write_word(out, 16, 2);  // number of bits per sample (use a multiple of 8)

///DATA
size_t data_chunk_pos = out.tellp();
out << "data----";

//~~CONTENTS
for (int i = 0; i < gemz.size(); i++) {
    ifstream inn(gemz[i], std::ios::binary);
    inn.seekg(44);

    out << inn.rdbuf();
}

//~~CONTENTS

// (We'll need the final file size to fix the chunk sizes above)
size_t file_length = out.tellp();

// Fix the data chunk header to contain the data size
out.seekp(data_chunk_pos + 4);
write_word(out, file_length - data_chunk_pos + 8,4); //i added the 4 as the third arg, thanks to Remy

// Fix the file header to contain the proper RIFF chunk size, which is (file size - 8) bytes
out.seekp(0 + 4);
write_word(out, file_length - 8, 4);

out.close();

PlaySound(TEXT(pathpat + "\\voces\\_audiophiles\\output.wav".c_str()), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
PlaySound(pathpat + "\\voces\\_audiophiles\\output.wav".c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Comment: Try using a wchar string as path.

Comment: @Surt What might that look like? I thought that the c_str() method returned a wchar.

Comment: `std::ofstream` does not have a constructor that accepts a `std::string` as input. And `TEXT(pathpat + "\\voces\\_audiophiles\\output.wav".c_str())` is not valid code, `TEXT()` can only be used on **char/string literals** at compile-time, not on `char*` pointers at runtime.  The code shown should not even compile.

Comment: After copying your input files into the `data` chunk, make sure to write a pad byte if the chunk's final size is odd (the pad byte is not to be included in the size value that you write to the `data` chunk's header).  Also, you are not setting `size` to 4 when calling `write_word()` to write the `data` chunk size, so make sure `sizeof(size_t)` is actually 4 on your compiler or else you will corrupt the header. Since you explicitly specify `size` in all of your other calls to `write_word()`, I assume this particular call was just an oversight.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The cplusplus website has this as the constructor example: `std::ofstream ofs ("test.txt", std::ofstream::out);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, my compiler says that `sizeof(size_t)` is 8

Comment: I changed the last `write_word` call to include the size of 4. Thanks. I have checked five different examples, and every time, my data chunk length is a multiple of 4.

Comment: @ZennyBadget that `ofstream` example is passing a string literal (which is a `const char[]`) to a constructor thst accepts a `const char*`, so the literal works fine. Your code, however, is passing a `std::string` instead (assuming `pathpat` is a `std::string`, which you did not show). `std::ofstream` does not have a constructor that takes a `std::string`. You would have to use `c_str()`. The code you have shown should not be compiling.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay. I tried using a string literal in the `ofstream`, removing `pathpat`, and also tried using a `const char*` and both didn't work. I also tried removing the `TEXT()` part from the `PlaySound` function. Still no change. The wav file is produced and works in wmp, it just won't play via `PlaySound`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ZennyBadget: Please update your question to show your latest code.  You are likely still doing something wrong with it. Are you *sure* all of your input files are encoded as PCM 16bit? You might also consider not manually writing everything from scratch to begin with. At least use the structs that the Win32 API defines for WAV files (`PCMWAVEFORMAT`, etc). You can use `ofstream::write()` to write them, instead of using `ofstream::put()` to write individual bytes.

Comment: @ZennyBadget: If you are not trying to write portable code that creates WAV files on multiple platforms, if you are just targetting Windows, I would suggest not using `std::ofstream` at all to create the WAV file. I would suggest using the Win32 multimedia API instead, specifically the `mmioOpen()`, `mmioCreateChunk()`, `mmioDescend()`/`mmioAscend()`, and `mmioWrite()`, functions. Let the API handle the complexities for you. I have been using these functions for years to create WAV files, they work very well.